# I made a prime finding program with python, could someone please confirm that it outputs only primes

Tags: python, primes

I tried to make a program that creates a list of all the primes up to some number, but I'm not completely sure that it would work for any input. I would also like to know, assuming it does work, how efficient it is compared to other prime finding algorithms.

```
n=1
k=input()
primes=[2]
def f(n):
   b, a = 1, 1
   for i in primes:
      a=((2*n+1)%i)
      b=b*a
   return b
while k > n:
   if f(n) >= 1:
      primes.append((2*n)+1)
      n=n+1
   else:
      n=n+1
      k=k+1
print primes
```

Comment: It doesn't even run... `  File "test.py", line 10
    while k > n:
               ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level`... did you even try it, before you posted it?

Comment: If it runs and you've tried it for at least `k=100` by manually checking the results, you could try posting it on codereview.stackchange.com

Comment: @RobertR No, `b` is not always 1. But yes, some comments what he/she is doing would be good.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works, and it is terribly inefficient.  In the function `f` you want to test if any of the primes found so far divides `2*n+1`.  There are two inefficiencies in the code.  First, even if `2*n+1` turns out to be divisible by 3, say, you calculate the remainder on division by all the other known primes.  Second, it is wasteful to multiply all the remainders together, since all you want to know is whether one of the remainders is 0.
The body of `f` could be replaced by

```
return any((2*n+1)%p == 0 for p in primes)
```

This will quit at the first 0 remainder, and avoid the unnecessary multiplications.

Even with this improvement, this is not an efficient algorithm, compared to others.  Even the ancient sieve of Eratosthenes would probably run faster, since it avoids doing any time-consuming divisions.  To put it mildly, prime-finding is a problem which has been the subject of a great deal of research for a great many years, and a lot of high-powered math has been aimed at it.  No one can expect to come up with a competitive algorithm without a great deal of prior study.  I Googled "prime-finding algorithms" and got about 9 million hits.

Still, this algorithm well may be sufficient for your purposes.